# How to change the CSS of all the elements in the page - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking for the best way to update stylesheet with `JavaScript` (runtime). So far I know I could do it with `querySelectorAll()`. That gives you all the elements match the query on the page.  The problem with this approach is that if a new element mount on the DOM. I would have to manually replace its style, and it gets messier.

`document.styleSheets` might be the solution I am looking for, but I can't seem to find an easy way to find and replace CSS rules and/or properties. It has few helpful functions such as `insertRule` and `addRule`. I am not sure how I can use them effectively to replace the CSS properties.

Any help would be appreciated!

`PS:` Although I would prefer `JavaScript`, but `jQuery` would work fine as well. I can find a way to convert `jQuery` to `JavaScript`

`Background:` There are few websites I use on daily basis such as `waffle.io` and I don't like their theme. I am trying to customize it with a `Chrome Extension` and `JavaScript`. Changing the `HTML` attributes would not help in this scenario, because `waffle.io` continuously updates the DOM. I want to run the `script` once at the beginning and I want the newly mounted elements to have the updated styles. Due to this continuous change in the DOM, I believe it is essential to update the CSS rules/properties in stylesheet itself. (I could be wrong)

Please let me know if its still unclear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: but do you know for a fact that the HTML element itself is being changed? if not, then you *can* manipulate the HTML element and be safe. based on my experience, the HTML element itself is *rarely* updated after it has been rendered. other elements in the body sure.. but the HTML element?

Comment: I think you are right... that make sense. I will give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: additionally, you can do some gnarly things with the DOM structure like inserting your own intermediary between the HTML tag and the BODY tag and setting classes on that: `var h = document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0]; f = document.createElement('foo'); f.appendChild(document.body); h.appendChild(f); ` it feels super dirty, but it might work to capture the cases where the HTML element itself *is* being updated for whatever reason.

Comment: You are right... its a dirty way of doing it. I am about to find out if `HTML` tag changes. If it doesn't then I will stick to the solution you proposed earlier. For example `waffle.io` uses `AngularJS` and technically they can change the `head` and `html`. I am guilty of doing this once lol. I am hoping that they don't.

Comment: I’d say you actually want a _user stylesheet_, instead of messing around with JS.

Comment: @misorude, how would I about doing that?

Comment: https://beamtic.com/custom-style-sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% certain what you are trying to do, but what you could do, is to introduce a class to the html tag that acts as the override that you are trying to achieve.

So by default you would have:

```
<html class="normal">
...
</html>
```

and with javascript you would just replace/add the class "updated" or whatever:

```
<html class="normal updated">
...
</html>
```

Then in your stylesheets, you can have:

```
.normal .foo { /* normal styles */ }
.normal.updated .foo { /* the other styles */ }
```

In this way, `.updated` will take predecence over `.normal` for the `.foo` class because it will have higher specificity. This might be the easiest way to target *all* elements on the page with JS and CSS if I understood your question correctly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I like this solution so far. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little unclear what you are trying to do but you can easily change the src attribute of an externally linked style sheet with js

Answer (score 0):

You can do something of this sort. Here I am changing font size of all the elements. Similarly you can use other properties.

Either you can add a class on `html` element or just add a property to `html` element in css.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html {
        font-size: 10px
      }

      * {
        font-size: 1rem
      }

      .first {
        font-size: 1.2rem
      }

      .second {
        font-size: 1.5rem
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      function increaseFontSize (key) {
        const fontSize = key === 'small' ?  '10px' : '16px'
        document.documentElement.style.fontSize = fontSize
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="increaseFontSize('large')">+</button>
    <button onclick="increaseFontSize('small')">-</button>
    <p class="first">
      The constraints parameter is a MediaStreamConstraints object with two members: video and audio, describing the media types requested. Either or both must be specified. If the browser cannot find all media tracks with the specified types that meet the constraints given, then the returned promise is rejected with NotFoundError.
    </p>

    <p>
      The constraints parameter is a MediaStreamConstraints object with two members: video and audio, describing the media types requested. Either or both must be specified. If the browser cannot find all media tracks with the specified types that meet the constraints given, then the returned promise is rejected with NotFoundError.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```